# Error while migrate from Godaddy to other host wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, migration

I got an error while migrating the wordpress site from Godaddy. The error is "Invalid User Action". This is first time i see this error and i have tried all steps like

1. rename htaccess file.
2. rename plugin folder
3. remove user.ini file.
   I have also on the debug error but no luck.

Please help me if anybody know anything about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue, and it seems this is related to a specific child Divi theme, in my case Phoenix which has the exact error message coded in the plugin.

I had done a migration from production to development, but I had wanted to change the prefix as well.  So what I was missing was the updates to allow the admin user to have the correct permissions, as stated in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219194/locked-out-of-wordpress-admin-dashboard-after-server-move

So in this child theme's case, it was looking for an 'import' permission which wasn't available and thus gave that error (but even if not for the child theme, you would have ran into permission errors getting into the admin dashboard).

So I have it now working in development after following the fixes above.

Comment: Are you able to please include the relevant code/response from the link just in case it gets taken down?